# Normal approximation to binomial

Tags: statistics

A firm with many traveling sales persons decides to check the salespersons' travel expenses to see if they are correctly reported. An auditor for the firm selects 200 expense reports at random to audit. What is the probability that more than 40 of these 200 sampled reports will be incorrect when in fact only 10% of the firms' reports are improperly documents. Use and justify normal approximation to binomial.

I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly so here's my attempt :

mean = np = 0.7 x 200 (is it 0.7?)
Standard Variance = 200 x 0.3 x 0.7 =>Standard Deviation = 6.48
z = (x - mean)/SD = (39.5-70)/7.07 = -4.31
P(z > -4.31) = 1

P.S : This is just a set of sample questions that I'm practising on for the coming up exam. Not an assignment. I appreciate straight forward answer instead of hints.

Answer (score 1):

The expected number of bad expense accounts is $0.1\cdot200=20$: that’s the mean that you should be using. Since you’re interested in the probability of **more than** $40$ bad expense accounts, you want to set your cutoff at $40.5$, not $39.5$. The variance is

$$200\cdot0.1\cdot(1-0.1)=200\cdot0.09\;,$$

and the standard deviation is

$$\sqrt{200\cdot0.09}=\sqrt{200}\cdot\sqrt{0.09}=10\sqrt2\cdot0.3=3\sqrt2\approx 4.24264\;.$$

Your cutoff of $40.5$ therefore translates to about

$$\frac{40.5}{4.24264}\approx 9.5459$$

standard units, so the probability of getting over $40$ bad expense accounts is very, very small.

Comment: I suspect that the cutoff should be closer to $20.5$.  In absolute terms the normal approximation may be reasonable here but in relative terms it is poor:  `1 - pbinom(40, size=200, prob=0.1)` gives `7e-06` while `1 - pnorm(40.5, mean=200*0.1, sd=sqrt(200*0.1*0.9))` gives `7e-07` using R